# How can I convert ranked table with pandas?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

Let me simplify my problem for easy explanation.

I have a pandas DataFrame table with the below format:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  3  2
1  3  1  2
2  3  2  1
```

The numbers in each row present ranks of columns.
For example, the order of the first row is {a, c, b}.

How can I convert the above to the below ?

```
   1  2  3
0  a  c  b
1  c  a  b
2  c  b  a
```

I googled all day long. But I couldn't find any solutions until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are just mapping one value to another and renaming the columns, e.g.:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,3], 'b':[3,1,2], 'c':[2,2,1]})
>>> df = df.applymap(lambda x: df.columns[x-1])
>>> df.columns = [1,2,3]
>>> df
   1  2  3
0  a  c  b
1  c  a  b
2  c  b  a
```